# Unidentified UI issue

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-ui, jsp, jakarta-ee

I found some unusual characters appearing on our web application.

It looks very similar to what i found on yahoo india website. http://in.yahoo.com/

If you open [this link](http://in.yahoo.com/) using firefox ( i used 19.0.2 ) ,then after going down through left side navigation , movies -> News -> omg! -> screen -> `<skip > -> <skip>` -> HERE -> HERE

what kind of character is this and what could be the cause .In IE & Chrome these appear as small boxes.

Is there anything to do with i18n or character encoding.

Its not always or with all browsers, its happening for some people in my organization, in IE particularly.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a charset problem or is it abnormal to have these links?

Comment: Malay Character sets missing. Try safari

Comment: i am not sure , but in my application it comes only for some people and that is on IE.

Comment: if character sets missing, then is there any way to fix this .

Comment: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95290

Comment: `If you open this link using ...`: where is the link?

Comment: @Aubin , its  http://in.yahoo.com/